# Get Click event on elements inside canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics

I am working on unity project which has a 3D sphere (Rotatable and zoomable). Inside that sphere there are 121 Quads (Tiles). Sphere is visible like google earth and inside a Canvas. I want to get Click events on Quads so that I can know on which Quad user has clicked and app can perform action according to that.

Is there any way to do this? I have heard that Canvas is just like a Bitmap Image.

Comment: Can you share the xaml?

Comment: Its not in xaml , Its all created in c# using a frame work UFrame

Answer (score 0):

If you able to get particular Quard details, if `(x,y)` co-ordinate given then, you can archive it by attaching click event to `canvas`.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
// Add event listener for click events.
elem.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var x = event.pageX - elemLeft;
    var y = event.pageY - elemTop;
    // Collision detection between clicked offset and element.
    quardElements.forEach(function (element) {
        if (y > element.top && y < element.top + element.height
                && x > element.left && x < element.left + element.width) {
            //do your stuff here
        }
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: Its not possible sphere is 3d (Rotatable and Zoomable)